# Вывод данных из базы в динамическую таблицу

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Имеется вот такая примерно таблица -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">    <h:head>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
  <title>#{msgs.pageTitle}</title>    </h:head>    <h:body>
  <h:form>              
     <h:dataTable value="#{customerBean.all}" var="customer"
                  styleClass="customers" headerClass="customersHeader"
                  columnClasses="name, text">
        <h:column>
           <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.customerIdHeader}</f:facet>
           #{customer.id}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
           <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.NDOKHeader}</f:facet>
           #{customer.NDOK}
        </h:column>
                     <h:column>
           <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.SODRABHeader}</f:facet>
           #{customer.SODRAB}
        </h:column>
     </h:dataTable>
  </h:form>    </h:body> </html>
```

Как написать правильный код с использованием jdbc, который бы подключался к базе и получал данные, а затем они попадали в данную таблицу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Для подключения к MSSQL вам поднадобится соответствующий драйвер. В Maven Central его нету, поэтому вам будет нужно самостоятельно добыть внутри каталога установки драйвера:

```
<installation directory>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\sqljdbc.jar
<installation directory>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\sqljdbc4.jar
<installation directory>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\sqljdbc41.jar
<installation directory>\sqljdbc_<version>\<language>\sqljdbc42.jar
```

согласно [документации Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Скачать драйвер можно [с сайта Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774).

(Поясню на всякий случай: installation directory не надо никуда прописывать - это просто путь до драйвера при обычной установке из инсталлятора. Если у вас уже все скачано, достаточно добавить драйвер в CLASSPATH.)

Далее этот драйвер нужно добавить в CLASSPATH любым методом, специфичным для вашего проекта. Например, если вы собираете вручную из консоли, то это будет нечто вроде:

```
CLASSPATH =.;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\sqljdbc42.jar

CLASSPATH =.:/home/usr1/mssqlserverjdbc/Driver/sqljdbc_4.2/enu/sqljdbc42.jar
```

Если вы используете IntelliJ IDEA, то это делается так:

- нужно зайти в настройки проекта (File->Project Structure)
- в разделе Modules найти ваш модуль
- на вкладке Dependencies в самом низу нажать на плюсик
- выбрать "JARs or Directories"
- добавить нужную директорию

Если используется Maven, то есть проблема, в Maven Central нету этого артефакта, то есть его придется оформить самостоятельно.

Для серьезных больших проектов, самый правильный способ - поднять собственный репозиторий. На выбор, например, есть [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) и [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus/solution-overview). Как работать с этими инструментами - описывать слишком долго, не влезет в максимальный размер ответа. Скорей всего, у вас не тот случай, но я был обязан предупредить.

Для небольших проектов, можно установить нужный jar в локальный репозиторий Maven. Про это на сайте Maven есть [специальная документация](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html). Вкратце, достаточно просто запустить в терминале строчку:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<путь до джарки с жрайвером без угловых скобочек> -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver \
    -DartifactId=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver -Dversion=4.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

и далее добавить в `pom.xml` новую зависимость вида:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

В общем, добавление новой джарки с сборку проекта очень зависит от характеристик вашего проекта, способов сборки, деплоймента, итп. Тут все каждый решает для себя.

2) Далее у нас есть допустим Entity класс:

```
public class Customer {

    private Integer id;
    private String NDOK;
    private String SODRAB;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(Integer id, String NDOK, String SODRAB) {
        this.id = id;
        this.NDOK = NDOK;
        this.SODRAB = SODRAB;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNDOK() {
        return NDOK;
    }

    public void setNDOK(String NDOK) {
        this.NDOK = NDOK;
    }

    public String getSODRAB() {
        return SODRAB;
    }

    public void setSODRAB(String SODRAB) {
        this.SODRAB = SODRAB;
    }
}
```

3) Далее создаем managed bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CustomerBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6081417964063918994L;

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Connection connect = null;

        //Привел пример, как указать еще и в url, это необязательно
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
     "databaseName=CustomerDatabase;user=user;password=password";

        String username = "user";
        String password = "password";

        try {

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            // System.out.println("Connection established"+connect);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("in exec");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        PreparedStatement pstmt = connect
                .prepareStatement("select id, NDOK, SODRAB from Customer");
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            customer.setNDOK(rs.getString("NDOK"));
            customer.setSODRAB(rs.getString("SODRAB"));

            customers.add(customer);

        }

        // close resources
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        connect.close();

        return customers;

    }

}
```

4) Передаете данные в таблицу способом, описанным в стартовом посте.

5) PROFIT

Comment: Ох, большое спасибо вам за помощь. Но вот тут такое дело - подчеркивает SetId, SetNDOK. SetSODRAB, Customer.add(car) во второй части кода, как это поправить? И еще - installation directory и CLASSPATH - куда следует прописать? Драйвер уже скачан.

Comment: обновил ответ: добавил описание добавления джарки в CLASSPATH, добавил мусор из геттеров-сеттеров в класс чтобы у вас не было все подчеркнуто красным, поправил ошибки в наименованиях

Comment: customer.add(customer); - вот это еще как то надо описать в классе Customers - я прав?
Большое спасибо за помощь, она была крайне полезной. А вы сами как вот все это изучали?

Comment: поправил очередную опечатку. Рекомендую вникнуть в смысл написанного, тогда не придется ждать, что вам напишут идеальный код. Это же все-таки не готовая программа, а просто идея, от которой вам можно отталкиваться. Я это вообще не изучал - у нас используются похожие технологии, а адаптация под ваши технологии делается с помощью пары вопросов в Google Search. Все что я умею - это хорошо гуглить.

Comment: Да просто как-то задача свалилась в авральных условиях и потому четко сесть и разобраться проблематично было... Еще раз спасибо за помощь, удачи вам!